# How to add additional libc dependencies to Quarkus Jib image?

Tags: quarkus, jib, yourkit

I'm trying to run the YourKit agent inside the container. But when I run my application I get: `Could not find agent library /home/jboss/app/libyjpagent.so in absolute path, with error: libc.musl-x86_64.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

How can I install additional libc libs needed for YourKit to run in Quarkus with Jib?

Answer (score -1):

YourKit agent is statically linked. It has no additional dependencies. Does your Alpine is 64 bit? What is optput of ldd -v /home/jboss/app/libyjpagent.so ?

Comment: So if I I'm correct Quarkus uses openjdk base images. I used the Azul base image for Java 11 and it works now...